# How do I copy files from one directory with sub-folders to another directory with sub-folders based on folder name?

Tags: python

sorry say i have:

`directory A at the path = /Users/John/Desktop/test_1`

The folder structure in directory A looks as such:

```
./fashion
./.DS_Store
./fashion/clothes
./fashion/.DS_Store
./fashion/2.jpg
./fashion/3.jpg
./fashion/1.jpg
./fashion/clothes/sneakers
./fashion/clothes/.DS_Store
./fashion/clothes/sneakers/2.jpg
./fashion/clothes/sneakers/3.jpg
./fashion/clothes/sneakers/1.jpg
```

`directory B at the path = /Users/John/Desktop/test_2`

The folder structure in directory B looks as such:

```
./fashion
./.DS_Store
./fashion/clothes
./fashion/.DS_Store
./fashion/clothes/sneakers
./fashion/clothes/high_heels
./fashion/clothes/.DS_Store
```

I'm trying to copy the files from directory A to directory B based off folder name match such that in directory B, you have the below. If the folder_name doesn't exist in directory B, don't copy the image.

**edit:** the exact file path doesn't have to match, it's just IF(the name of the folder in directory A) == (name of folder in directory B), copy the contents of folder A into folder B. otherwise, do nothing.

```
fashion: img1, img2

fashion > clothes: img1, img2

fashion > clothes > sneakers: img1, img2

fashion > clothes > high-heels: {}
```

Thank you again!

Comment: you'll also need to include the device you are trying to do this on (mac or pc)

Comment: you wan to keep also the subfolders or only the files in the second folder?

Comment: does directory B exist?

Comment: sorry made edits to the question because it was unclear, thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

you can try shitil:

```
import shutil
import os

path_a = '/Users/John/Desktop/test_1'
path_b ='/Users/John/Desktop/test_2'


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_b):
    similar_path = root.replace(path_b, path_a)
    if os.path.exists(similar_path):
        for file_path in (os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir(similar_path) if os.path.isfile(x)):
            print(f'File: {file_path} moved to --->> {root}')
            shutil.copy(file_path, root)
```

Comment: it ran but it didn't place the images in the right folders :(

Comment: try now, didn't have all the details in the beginning

Comment: i wasn't as clear as i should be because i don't need the exact same file path to match. just the folder name regardless of what level in the folder structure it is. will update with more details, sorry again!

Comment: not getting any output, i do a print similar_path and it's walking through path b and replacing path b with path a but nothing gets printed afterwards, the {file_path} moved printf isn't getting printed

Comment: maybe your folders paths are not really similar, I just tested in the way you described the problem and worked...

Comment: ahh I'm running this in jupyter and my current directory is set to that working directory. should i be changing the current directory to /Users/John? Or where should my working directory be? I think os.path.abspath is throwing things off for me

Comment: depends, if you can access directory A and directory B from Jupiter you just have to  set path_a and path_b with the folder's path

Comment: This is my output

File: /Users/John/.DS_Store moved to  /Users/John/Desktop/test_2/      File /Users/John/.DS_Store moved to /Users/John/Desktop/test_2/fashion     File /Users/John/.DS_Store moved to /Users/John/Desktop/test_2/fashion/clothes

Seems to get stuck on /Users/John/.DS_Store
Apologies for all the questions

Comment: list some of the files(with full path) that you expect to be moved (where  with full path)

Comment: added the full path above in the question, do i have to do an os.chdir('Users/John/Desktop')??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#operating-system-interface and the modul shutil. Easy file handling.